# Mapping a backbone.collection to a specific property

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I'm trying to build a basic structure with backbone.js. My issue is that the server will not directly return an array of objects in json format, but an object which has the the desired array of objects embeded inside:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 2}, "objects": [{...},{...} {...}]}
```

In this case what I really want in my collection is the "objects" property. So when I try to build a backbone collection, I'm not sure if I should iterate and add them manually or there is someway I can map it directly to the objects property of the object.

Hope thats understandable... thanks!

Comment: You need to define a custom parse function, how-to is on the backbone.js documentation page.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020123/backbone-js-fetching-a-more-complex-data-and-using-as-a-collection/10027237#10027237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [collection.parse(response)](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) function:

> parse is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are
>   returned by the server, in fetch. The function is passed the raw
>   response object, and should return the array of model attributes to be
>   added to the collection. The default implementation is a no-op, simply
>   passing through the JSON response. Override this if you need to work
>   with a preexisting API, or better namespace your responses.