# Access Nested Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Below is what i am populating my collection with (FacetModels)

How do I access the AvailableValues[] array

> "FacetModels":[
>   {
>   "FacetDisplayLabel":null,
>   "SelectedValues":[],
>   "AvailableValues":[],
>   "UnknownResults":0,
>   "ActionURI":null,
>   "FacetGroupName":"Category",
>   "FacetGroupFriendlyId":"SourceCategory",
>   "FacetGroupOrder":10,
>   "AllowSuggestions":false
>   },

This is my view, as you will see all i have access to is the array of FacetModels, I need to be able to pass FacetModels[0].AvailableValues.Name so I can display each category Name

```
CategoryListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "category",
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.template = _.template( $("#categorylist_template").html());
    },
    render: function () {
        var category = this.model
        console.log(category);
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Display from console

a.Model {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
ActionURI: null
AllowSuggestions: false
AvailableValues: Array[8]
0: Object
ActionURI: "/api/search?firstname=thomas&firstname_variants=true&lastname=smith&region=all&sourcecategory=armed%20forces%20utf0026%20conflict"
Count: 8943
DisplayLabel: "Armed Forces & Conflict"
IsUnknown: false
Name: "Armed Forces & Conflict"
**proto**: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
length: 8
**proto**: Array[0]
FacetDisplayLabel: null
FacetGroupFriendlyId: "SourceCategory"
FacetGroupName: "Category"
FacetGroupOrder: 10
SelectedValues: Array[0]
UnknownResults: 0
**proto**: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: r
**proto**: Object

Comment: What is the model of your view? Is AvailableValues a collection, or just an attribute with an array? What is displayed in your console? And so on...

Comment: I've added the console output. It is in my model as an attribute but part of an array.  ie FacetModels[0].AvailableValues[]

Answer (score 1):

Inside your view the javascript array is available through this.model.get('AvailableValues'). If you need Available values to be a Backbone Collection, you can override parse to populate the AvailableValues property with a collection instead of an array.

There are some other SO questions that have examples of this:

- [backbone-js-fetching-a-more-complex-data-and-using-as-a-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020123/backbone-js-fetching-a-more-complex-data-and-using-as-a-collection)
- [how-to-override-backbones-parse-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037984/how-to-override-backbones-parse-function)

Comment: I didn't realise that it was this.model.get('AvailableValues')
So how do i now get at say 'DisplayLabel' ("AvailableValues":[
{
"DisplayLabel":"Census, Land & Surveys",)

Comment: AvailableValues will be a javascript array at that point. You can access value of DisplayLabel through: AvailableValues[0]["DisplayLabel"]. I'm sure you will be iterating through available values rather than accessing through [0], but the idea is to read the value from an individual available value.